# %0 is not replaced by server name when used with Apache's ProxyPassMatch

Tags: regex, apache, virtualhost, proxypass

**Problem:**

%0 is not replaced by server name (i.e. test.local) when used with ProxyPassMatch.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  UseCanonicalName Off

  # %0 is replaced by server name (works)
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/mattes/sites/%0

  # %0 is replaced by an empty string (problem!)
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/Users/mattes/sites/%0/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Work-around:**

I found an interesting blog post here: http://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/225/Apache-2.2-Proxy.html. Basically, Michael uses RewriteEngine to save variables for later usage. Something like this will work, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/mattes/sites/%0

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule .* - [E=SERVER_NAME:%{SERVER_NAME}]
  ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
  ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/Users/mattes/sites/ \
                                                    ${SERVER_NAME}$1 interpolate

</VirtualHost>
```

While it works, i consider this to be a not-so-nice work-around. I am also getting errors like "AH00111: Config variable ${SERVER_NAME} is not defined".

---

**Has anybody an idea how to solve this?**

Comment: Is it just me or does this question kind of fit "[your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"

Comment: I see your point. Since the work-around throws warnings, i don't think this issue is solved.

Comment: Depending on the configuration of apache2, the work-around from above doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this configuration with Apache 2.4:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%0"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:19054/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

`vhosts` directory contains directories with domain names that Apache will dynamically match to each request. All PHP files are then matched and their requests are forwarded to PHP FPM process listening at `127.0.0.1:19054`.

This configuration works with further rewrite rules defined inside virtual hosts directories.