# Apache: Use VirtualDocumentRoot wildcard with an environment variable?

Tags: apache, variables, dynamic, wildcard, environment

We've got a development sandbox which uses VirtualDocumentRoot to easily handle new developer sandboxes. I'd like to use the %1 value from VirtualDocumentRoot to set an environment variable for the app.  I've tried %1, $1, ${1}, %{1}, but nothing sticks.

Would really appreciate help from an apache guru.  Here's the snippet:

```
<VirtualHost [ip]:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%1/public
ServerName [web].com
ServerAlias *.[web].com
ServerAdmin [some email]
SetEnv SANDBOX %1
ErrorLog logs/[web].com-error_log
CustomLog logs/[web].com-access_log common
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191546/0-is-not-replaced-by-server-name-when-used-with-apaches-proxypassmatch